# In a medieval city how large a market was needed relative to population?

Tags: middle-ages, economy, trade

In a large medieval city fed by the agricultural product of the area, plus imports such as grains, spices, fish, etc. and also serving as a regional hub for the exchange of trade goods, what determined the placement and number of market locations in the city? How big was a market was needed relative to city population in terms of vendors and space?

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it lacks prior research, is too broad and unclear. Which region, period etc needs to be detailed, and prerequisites like [privileges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Town_privileges) examined, *before* a useful answer can be attempted.

Comment: You might look at [central place theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_place_theory); I believe the theory has been discredited, but the arguments to support/refute it may be of use in refining your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get some information concerning the number of markets relative to population by looking at the Wikipedia page on [Market Towns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Market_town). One specific tidbit there might be of use to you (emphasis mine).

> The primary purpose of a market town is the provision of goods and
> services to the surrounding locality.[1](http://www.domesdaybook.co.uk/life.html#:%7E:text=The%20population%20of%20England%20at,have%20been%20in%20Roman%20times.) Although market towns were
> known in antiquity, their number increased rapidly from the 12th
> century. Market towns across Europe flourished with an improved
> economy, a more urbanised society and the widespread introduction of a
> cash-based economy.[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domesday_Book) **The Domesday Book of 1086 lists 50 markets in
> England**. Some 2,000 new markets were established between 1200 and
> 1349.[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Death_in_England#England_in_the_mid-14th_century) The burgeoning of market towns occurred across Europe around the same time.

This gives us some specific information on a specific time and location, *50 markets in England* at the time of the [Doomsday Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domesday_Book).  We can get some [numbers](http://www.domesdaybook.co.uk/life.html#:%7E:text=The%20population%20of%20England%20at,have%20been%20in%20Roman%20times.) on the population at the time of the doomsday book :

> The total population of England in 1086 cannot be calculated
> accurately from Domesday for several reasons: only the heads of
> households are listed; major cities like London and Winchester were
> omitted completely; there are no records of nuns, monks, or people in
> castles. **The population of England at the time of Domesday has been
> tentatively estimated at between 1¼ and 2 million**. However, these
> figures are much lower than the 4 million people there are estimated
> to have been in Roman times.

So if we do the math, we can get those 50 markets divided into the population across England in 1086 showing ***each market covered a population of 25,000 to 30,000 people***.  This is oversimplification just to get a numerical 'ball park' figure, but interestingly it seems to match the figures provided in [another answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/62721/16951) by @Pieter Geerkens, which showed 5 markets in a city of 125,000 for one market covering 25,000 people.

You can look at the first quote and see that the distribution of markets changes quite a bit a little later in the middle ages (12th to 14th centuries):

> their number increased rapidly from the 12th
> century. Market towns across Europe flourished with an improved
> economy, a more urbanised society and the widespread introduction of a
> cash-based economy...Some 2,000 new markets were established between 1200 and
> 1349.

Running numbers on England again, but picking just at the maximum population estimates before the [depopulation event of the plague](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Death_in_England#England_in_the_mid-14th_century), we find a population estimate of 6,000,000 having access to some 2000 markets, giving us ***one market per each 3000*** residents. A major difference showing that variation in time and conditions, all still within the medieval period.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit late in the period, but this [1572 map of Antwerp](https://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection/search/366878), with a [population that year of about 125,000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_Antwerp) lists at least 5 markets in the legend:

[image]

- 13. Die Grote Marct. - The Big Market.
      Centre, just north of the main church
      [image]
- 14. [Die Ossemarct. - The Ox Market.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Peeter_van_Bredael_-_The_Old_Ox_Market_in_Antwerp.jpg)
      Just inside the East Wall, between the two main gates
      [image]
- 15. Die Peerdemar[ct] - The Horse[?] Market.
      One block north of 14
      [image]
- 16. [Die Ve[e]marct. - The Cattle Market](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veemarkt_(handel))
      Three blocks north of 13.
      [image]
- 17. Die Vischmarct - The Fish Market
      South of the main dock
      [image]

[image: 1572 map of Antwerp]

Note that horsemeat is popular in much of France and the Low Countries; and both "*Cattle market*" and "*Horse Market*" may both be referring to two styles of butchery rather than to livestock. To my mind, livestock markets are more likely to be locate outside the city walls than inside - the former locations per force catering primarily to the **households** of the city.

---

This slightly later [map of Amsterdam dates to 1593](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1d/Cornelis_anthonisz_vogelvluchtkaart_amsterdam.JPG/1024px-Cornelis_anthonisz_vogelvluchtkaart_amsterdam.JPG). It lacks the definitive legend, but there a couple of likely market locations visible upon inspection.

[image: Map of Amsterdam 1593]

Many thanks to [LangLangC](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/26786/l%D0%B0ngl%D0%B0ng%D0%A1) for translation and spotting assistance.

Comment: ['Vemarct' is genral livestock](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vee#Dutch) & ['Ossemarct'](https://nds-nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ossemart) /  [ox market](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Peeter_van_Bredael_-_The_Old_Ox_Market_in_Antwerp.jpg)

Comment: Aiming for Dutch/Flemish, which do form a continuum with (esp low) German: https://www.antwerpen.be/info/5b0fb767a67793f7a36609a6/sociaal-centrum-veemarkt-antwerpen- https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veemarkt_(handel)

Comment: Last detail: place names most often have historic origin, so that all those markets were really where the live beasts were traded (as well as the meat (compare the reasoning for 18: meat house/butcher's guild hall rebuilding). And in those towns/cities live animals on sale were as much a common sight in the centre back then (certainly in medieval times) as it is now still in Wuhan… ;) 'Mainly just horses in the streets' is 'a bit' later than the map.

Comment: @LаngLаngС: Got it; that makes much sense on reflection. Great find with that Bredael painting of the Ox market!

Comment: The tendency is of course to push away the filthiest trades to the margins or even outside an ever growing city. There are a few books on that town available for free [example](https://lib.ugent.be/en/catalog/rug01:001873615), showing that just below the grote marct the vemarct once was, but got replaced for an 'egg market' (street still existing today "Eiermarkt") (not depicted, as a few others, so consequently, the map only depicts the biggest selling centres?)

Comment: @Random: No offense taken.